# Using google sheets through python in the most simple way

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, python-module

So basically I am making a discord bot that takes trades for ingame items on a game I play and stores the order in a google sheet. What would be the easiest way to do this through python, I know how to do all the bot stuff but when it comes to accessing a google sheet, searching through it and collecting certain rows of information I cant find much that helps. What module would I use to make this easiest as possible, the module needs to be able to search through the sheet for specific values in one column, find the first find the first empty cell in a column as well as collect  all the information from a row. If anyone knows a good module for doing this it would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have set up the OAuth and all that kind of stuff for the sheets api, I saw that there was a bunch of modules that make accessing the sheet easier however so I was wondering which one was the best at making the coding easier as I am not super experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Use Googlesheets API to get the data and then pandas to read in the data as a dataframe. Once you have the dataframe, Pandas can accomplish this in various ways: *"needs to be able to search through the sheet for specific values in one column, find the first empty cell in a column as well as collect all the information from a row"*

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import pandas as pd

SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'sheet ID' # your sheet ID
SAMPLE_NAME = 'sheet name' # your sheet name
RANGE = '!A1:D2' # your row/col sheet range
TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json' # path to your token file
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'] 
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = SAMPLE_NAME + RANGE 

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_PATH, SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values[1:], columns=values[0])
```

Adapted from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python